# How to grant access to role for the tables that are created today

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, oracle19c, sql-grant

How to grant access to role for the tables that are created today :

```
grant select on ( select 
       object_name as table_name
from sys.all_objects
where object_type = 'TABLE'
-- excluding some Oracle maintained schemas
and owner not in ('ANONYMOUS','CTXSYS','DBSNMP','EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS', 
  'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS','OWBSYS','ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS','OUTLN', 
  'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','SYS','SYSMAN','SYSTEM', 'TSMSYS','WK_TEST','WKSYS', 
  'WKPROXY','WMSYS','XDB','APEX_040000', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DIP', 
  'FLOWS_30000','FLOWS_FILES','MDDATA', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'XS$NULL',
  'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'PUBLIC')  
and created > sysdate -1
)  to  PSREAD_ROLE_W;
```

This query is not working. I am not sure how to pass the selected values in order to grant the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run this SQL, generate the output and execute the SQL generated.
Or the other option is to USE dynamic SQL and execute immediate to run the SQL

```
    SELECT ' GRANT SELECT ON ' ||    object_name || ' to PSREAD_ROLE_W; ' 
from sys.all_objects obj   where object_type = 'TABLE'
and created > sysdate -1
```

Answer (score 1):

you will not run your sql successfully because you essentially need 'dynamic sql', you may need write a piece of block of pl/sql as below in SqlPlus.

```
begin
for tab in (select owner,object_name
    from sys.all_objects
    where object_type = 'TABLE'
    -- excluding some Oracle maintained schemas
    and owner not in ('ANONYMOUS','CTXSYS','DBSNMP','EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS', 
      'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS','OWBSYS','ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS','OUTLN', 
      'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','SYS','SYSMAN','SYSTEM', 'TSMSYS','WK_TEST','WKSYS', 
      'WKPROXY','WMSYS','XDB','APEX_040000', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DIP', 
      'FLOWS_30000','FLOWS_FILES','MDDATA', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'XS$NULL',
      'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'PUBLIC')
loop
    execute immediate 'grant select on ' || tab.owner || '.' || tab.object_name || ' to PSREAD_ROLE_W';
end loop;
end;
/
```

try this code with sqlplus, if your need call it from jdbc, you still need create a named procedure and then call from java code.